# GWT - java.security.AccessControlException: access denied for serializer in ubuntu/tomca6 deployment

Tags: gwt, tomcat6, gwt-rpc

I am trying to deploy my gwt app to tomcat6 under ubuntu 9.10 and get 
the (i suppose known to many of you) 
"java.security.AccessControlException: access denied" error (Full 
exception can be found at the end). I have searched the net in general and found that the Java default security 
permissions are preventing the serializer from accessing my classes 
private members (they do have getters and setters) and that i should 
add to tomcat policy with a file at /etc/tomcat6/policy.d/60gwt.policy 
the following: 
grant codeBase "file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/-" { 
    permission java.security.AllPermission; 
}

Although i have done that (and i understand the implications) i still 
get the same error, no matter how many times i restart the server. The 
next step would problably be to disable tomcats security manager 
completely but this app will eventually go into production and i d 
like to know what's going on here. Also, i'd rather not make any 
member variables public... 
Any ideas? 
cheers

SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call 
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied 
(java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) 
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission 
(AccessControlContext.java:323) 
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission 
(AccessController.java:546) 
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java: 
532) 
        at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible 
(AccessibleObject.java:107) 
        at 
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.seriali zeClass 
(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:694) 
        at 
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.seriali zeImpl 
(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:730) 
        at 
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.seriali zeClass 
(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:712) 
        at 
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.seriali zeImpl 
(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:730) 
        at 
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.seriali ze 
(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:612) 
        at 
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.write Object 
(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:129) 
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter 
$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:152) 
        at 
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.seriali zeValue 
(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:534) 
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponse(RPC.java:609) 
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure 
(RPC.java:383) 
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse 
(RPC.java:581) 
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall 
(RemoteServiceServlet.java:188) 
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost 
(RemoteServiceServlet.java:224) 
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost 
(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62) 
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637) 
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java: 
269) 
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517) 
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute 
(SecurityUtil.java:301) 
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege 
(SecurityUtil.java:162) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter 
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:283) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000 
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run 
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) 
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter 
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke 
(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke 
(StandardContextValve.java:191) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke 
(StandardHostValve.java:128) 
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke 
(ErrorReportValve.java:102) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke 
(StandardEngineValve.java:109) 
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service 
(CoyoteAdapter.java:293) 
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process 
(Http11Processor.java:849) 
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol 
$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583) 
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java: 
454) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, i solved the problem. I was actually using file:$ 
{catalina.base}webapps/- instead of file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps that 
i wrote previously.Tomcat config in /etc/default/tomcat says that if 
you don't set catalina.base then /var/lib/tomcat6/ is used by default 
but...

Answer (score 0):

Well anyway: GWT can not serialize this kind of exception because the type is not available in the emulated JRE library. So either you define it yourself via en supersource or you hande the exception on the server and make sure that you only throw supported exceptions.